# catch mysql pdo error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get to grips with pdo. I have the below function:

```
  function get_editusers($db)  
  {    
    $result = $db->query("SELECT firstname, middlename,surname,fullname,gender, birthdate,homelanguage,department,employeetype,employeestatus,idnumber FROM Persons where employeeid='$employeeid'"); 
    return $result; 
  } 
  $useredit = get_editusers($db);
```

how do I know if the query ran correctly? if it was not successful I would like a certain action to be performed but not sure how to 'catch' the error.

```
if($useredit="failed"){ action if failed} else { action if true}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you're using PDO, use prepared statements with bind arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function get_editusers($db){    
    try {
         $result = $db->query("SELECT firstname, middlename,surname,fullname,gender, birthdate,homelanguage,department,employeetype,employeestatus,idnumber FROM Persons where employeeid='$employeeid'"); 
         return $result; 
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
         return $ex;
    }
}

$result = get_editusers($db);
if(isset($result->errorInfo)){
    die($result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and then do you just use isset($ex) in the if statement?

Answer (score 1):

A simply try/catch block would work:

```
    try{
        $result = $db - > query("SELECT firstname, middlename,surname,fullname,gender, birthdate,homelanguage,department,employeetype,employeestatus,idnumber FROM Persons where employeeid='$employeeid'");
    return $result;
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception){
        return $exception;
    }
```

Or if you just want a true/false value returned rather than a specific exception:

```
    $result = $db -> query("SELECT firstname, middlename,surname,fullname,gender, birthdate,homelanguage,department,employeetype,employeestatus,idnumber FROM Persons where employeeid='$employeeid'");

    if (!$result){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for PDO this function retrieve the error information. Perhaps it helps.

[PDO errorinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)